# Existing JavaScript not working after rendering Laravel Livewire component

Tags: laravel-livewire, laravel-livewire-wiremodel

I have created livewire components for shop page and product items in my project. here is my code

Shop page ,

```
`@extends('layouts.frontend-layout')

@section('content')
@livewire('product.index', ['category' => $category] , key("category-{$category->id}"))
@endsection

@section('script')
<script>
    var priceSlider = document.getElementById('price-slider');

        noUiSlider.create(priceSlider, {
            start: [0, 50000],
            behaviour: 'drag',
            connect: true,
            range: {
                'min': 0,
                'max': 100000
            }
        });

        var FieldMin = document.getElementById('min-amount');
        var FieldMax = document.getElementById('max-amount');

        priceSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function (values, handle) {
            (handle ? FieldMax : FieldMin).innerHTML = values[handle];
        });

</script>
@endsection`
```

Shop page Component

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Product;

use App\Services\BrandService;
use App\Services\CategoryService;
use App\Services\ProductService;
use Livewire\Component;

class Index extends Component
{
    public $brand;
    public $category;
    protected $productService;
    protected $categoryService;
    protected $bannerService;
    protected $brandService;


    public $filters = [
        'brands' => [],
    ];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->productService = new ProductService();
        $this->categoryService = new CategoryService();
        $this->brandService = new BrandService();
    }

    protected function queryString()
    {
        return [
            'filters' => [
                'as' => 'q'
            ],
        ];
    }


    public function mount($category)
    {
        $this->category = $category;
    }

    public function updatedFilters()
    {
        return view('livewire.product.index', [
            'category' => $this->category,
            'brands' => $this->brandService->all(),
            'products' => $this->filterProducts($this->filters),
            'sub_categories' => $this->category?->get('sub_categories', [])
        ]);
    }

    public function render()
    {


        return view('livewire.product.index', [
            'category' => $this->category,
            'brands' => $this->brandService->all(),
            'products' => $this->filterProducts(),
            'sub_categories' => $this->category?->get('sub_categories', [])
        ]);
    }

    public function filterProducts()
    {
        $filters = collect($this->filters);
        $brandFilters = array_keys($filters->get('brands', []));
        $subCategoryFilders = array_keys($filters->get('category', []));

        $products = $this->category->get('products');

        if (count($brandFilters)) {
            $products = $products->filter(function ($item) use ($brandFilters) {
                return  !is_null($item['brand']) &&  in_array($item['brand']['slug'], $brandFilters);
            });
        }

        return $products;
    }
}
```

shop component view.

```
<div>
    <div class="page-header py-4">
        <div class="container container-wide">
            <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-between">
                <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-7 text-start">
                    <div class="breadcumb">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/">Home <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-right ms-1 me-2"></i></a></li>
                            <li><span>Shop</span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <h1 class="heading">{{$category?->get('name')}}</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-5 text-end">
                    <div class="short">
                        <span>Sort By:</span>
                        <select class="form-select" name="sorts" wire:model.live="filters.sort">
                            <option selected>Price (Low to High)</option>
                            <option value="1">Relevance</option>
                            <option value="2">Newest</option>
                            <option value="3">Alphabetical</option>
                            <option value="4">Price (High to Loq)</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="shop-section py-5">
        <div class="container container-wide">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 pe-lg-4 mb-4 mb-md-0">
                    <div class="shop-option">
                        <div class="price-range-box">
                            <div class="price-range mb-4">
                                <div class="option-heading">Price Range</div>
                                <div class="amount">LKR <span id="min-amount"></span> - <span id="max-amount"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="price-slider"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="selection-box">
                            <div class="option-heading mb-3">Brand</div>
                            @php
                            $brandsQuery = request()->query('q')['brands'] ?? [];
                            @endphp
                            <ul>
                                @foreach ($brands as $brand)
                                <li>
                                    <div class="checkbox-group">
                                        <input wire:model.live="filters.brands.{{$brand?->slug}}"
                                            value="{{$brand?->slug}}" class="rounded-checkbox"
                                            id="brand-{{$brand?->slug}}" type="checkbox" name="brands[]"
                                            {{array_key_exists($brand?->slug, $brandsQuery) ? 'checked' : null}}>
                                        <label for="brand-{{$brand?->slug}}">{{$brand?->name}}</label>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div class="selection-box">
                            <div class="option-heading mb-3">Categories</div>
                            <ul>
                                @foreach ($sub_categories as $subCat)
                                <li>
                                    <div class="checkbox-group">
                                        <input class="rounded-checkbox" id="{{$subCat?->get('slug')}}" type="checkbox"
                                            name="sub-categories"
                                            wire:model.live="filters.category.{{$subCat?->get('slug')}}"
                                            value="{{$subCat?->get('slug')}}">
                                        <label for="{{$subCat?->get('slug')}}">{{$subCat?->get('name')}}</label>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                @endforeach

                            </ul>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8">
                    <div class="row row-gap-30">
                        @if ($products)
                        @foreach ($products as $product)
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-6">
                            @livewire('product.item-card', ['product' => $product], key('shop-product-'.$product->get('id')))
                        </div>
                        @endforeach
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Product item component

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Product;

use Livewire\Component;

class ItemCard extends Component
{
    protected $product;

    public function mount($product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
    }


    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.product.item-card', ['product' => $this->product]);
    }
}
```

Product item component view

```
@php
$image_1 = $product?->images?->first()->url ?? null;
$image_2 = $product?->images?->get(1)->url ?? null;
@endphp
<div class="product {{$product?->new ? 'new-badge' : null}}">
    <a href="{{route('store.product', $product?->slug)}}" class="product-img">
        <img src="{{ $image_1 }}" data-img="{{ $image_2 }}" class="swim" alt="Dankotuwa -  {{$product?->name}}">
    </a>
    <div class="product-info">
        <a href="{{route('store.product', $product?->slug)}}">
            <div class="title"> {{$product?->name}} </div>
        </a>
        <div class="price my-3">
            <span class="sell-price">Rs. {{number_format($product?->discount_price, 1)}}</span>
            <span class="regular-price">Rs. {{number_format($product?->price, 1)}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="product-btn">
            <a type="button" class="btn btn-add-to-cart w-100">ADD TO CART</a>
            <a type="button" class="btn btn-add-to-cart"><i class="icon-gift"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I'm filtering, I get message "Uncaught Snapshot missing on Livewire component with id: BIxBer9Dq6XeLwb3RQeE" and, exsisting javascript functions are not working.

Comment: have you been able to solve this?